# Automapper cyclic reference causing update error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

EDIT: I also forgot to mention the data for the Flat models will eventually be pulled in from a seperate database instead of being manually created.

Batch update returned unexpected row count from update; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

is the error I receive when trying to use Automapper on two models with a cyclical reference to each other. I have an order which contains a list of order lines, who all reference back to the order. However I am also mapping from a flat model to each class. So the total number of models is:

- FlatPickingAssignment
- FlatPickingAssignmentItem
- PickingAssignment
- PickingAssignmentItem

To summarise, I map from the flat models to the normal models ( which have a cyclic reference ) and then save the Picking Assignment.

```
            FlatPickingAssignment pickingAssignment = new FlatPickingAssignment{
               HostId = "1002",
               AssignmentItems = assignmentItems,
               Description = "SecondAssignment",
               IsChase = false,
               GoalTime = 10.0,
               SummaryPromptType = 0,
               OverridePrompt = "",
               LocationCode = "LOC001",
               DirectLoad = 0,
               AllowDeliveryLocationOverride = 0,
               VehicleLicence = "",
               CustomerCode = "Cust002",
               TotalWeight = 0.0,
               TotalItems = 0,
               SingleSKU = false,
               SingleBatch = false,
               CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now,
               StartDate = System.DateTime.Now,
               EndDate = System.DateTime.Now
            };

            FlatPickingAssignmentItem t = new FlatPickingAssignmentItem
            {
                Id = 1,
                Assignment = pickingAssignment,
                ItemStatusId = 10,
                ItemTypeId = 10,
                LocationCode = "LOC002",
                PickedDate = System.DateTime.Now,
                CurrentUserOperatorId = "David",
                AssignedUserOperatorId = "Michael",
                ProductCode = "PROD001",
                PickingContainerId = 2,
                LotId = 1
            };

            assignmentItems.Add(t);
            pickingAssignment.AssignmentItems = assignmentItems;

            PickingAssignment translatedAssignment = translate(pickingAssignment);
            SavePickingAssignment(translatedAssignment);


private PickingAssignment translate(FlatPickingAssignment flatPickingAssignment)
        {
            try
            {
                Mapper.CreateMap<FlatPickingAssignmentItem, PickingAssignmentItem>()
                   .ForMember(dest => dest.Status, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<PAItemStatusResolver>())
                   .ForMember(dest => dest.Type, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<PAItemTypeResolver>())
                   .ForMember(dest => dest.Location, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<AssignmentItemLocationResolver>())
                   .ForMember(dest => dest.Product, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<ProductResolver>())
                   .ForMember(dest => dest.PickedContainer, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<PickingContainerResolver>())
                   .ForMember(dest => dest.Lot, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<LotsResolver>())
                   .ForMember(dest => dest.AssignedUser, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<AssignedUserResolver>())
                   .ForMember(dest => dest.CurrentUser, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CurrentUserResolver>())
                   .ForMember(dest => dest.Assignment, opt => opt.Ignore());

                Mapper.CreateMap<FlatPickingAssignment, PickingAssignment>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Customer, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomerResolver>())
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.DeliveryLocation, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<AssignmentLocationResolver>())
                    .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
                    {
                        foreach (var i in dest.AssignmentItems)
                            i.Assignment = dest;
                    });

                PickingAssignment pickingAssignment = Mapper.Map<FlatPickingAssignment, PickingAssignment>(flatPickingAssignment);

                return pickingAssignment;
            }
            catch
            {
                // add in later 
                return null;
            }


        }


 private void SavePickingAssignment(PickingAssignment assignment)
        {
            try {
                    using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
                    {
                        using (ITransaction t = session.BeginTransaction())
                        {
                            session.SaveOrUpdate(assignment);
                            t.Commit();
                        }
                    }
                }            
            catch { 
                // add in later 
            }            
        }
```

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong? If you need the resolvers too I can provide them

Comment: The likely culprit is your class mappings. I will venture a guess that a "many" relationship is mapped wrong. Also.. that is a gigantic amount of manual mapping. What use is Automapper to you if you are just going to manually map everything with it?

Comment: Hi, I added in an edit explaining where the Flat data comes from. With regards to the amount of resolvers its because the Item has references to other complex objects.

Comment: Automapper will map complex object graphs.. assuming those complex graphs each have mapping profiles of their own.